# unable to include jxbrowser in my jsp page

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, jxbrowser

I want to call jxbrowser in jsp page inside anchor tag or on button click.

i have created jxbrowser in java class.
this is the code of jxbrowser

HelloWorld.java

```
package web_browser;

import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import static java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Browser browser = new Browser();
        BrowserView browserView = new BrowserView(browser);

        final JTextField addressBar = new JTextField("http://localhost:8080/project_sarjan/newjsp.jsp");
        addressBar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                browser.loadURL(addressBar.getText());
            }
        });

        JPanel addressPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        addressPane.add(new JLabel(" URL: "), BorderLayout.WEST);
        addressPane.add(addressBar, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JxBrowser - Hello World");
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
      // frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.add(addressPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(browserView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //frame.setSize(1500, 1800);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        browser.loadURL(addressBar.getText());


    }

    private static Object getRootPane() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

this is my jsp page  where i want to include above page.

```
<%@ page import="web_browser.HelloWorld"%>

<a href=""  id="web"></a>
$('web').click(function{

<% HelloWorld h=new HelloWorld();
h.main(null);%>

});
```

Is there any another way to include jxbrowser inside jsp?

Comment: I recommend that you first include a simple program (e.g. display a simple JFrame) into your JSP web page. Once you successfully include this simple program, then using same approach you can include JxBrowser component as well.

Have you tried to include a simple application in JSP. Does it work?